# How to bind complex JSON data to kendo grid Angular?

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I am working on a Angular project where i need to bind a JSON data with nested Array in Kendo grid. For Example

```
user = [
    {
      userName: "staff Nepal",
      report: [
        {
          attendance: "00:00",
          date: "2019-10-16",
          fv: "",
          holiday: "",
          in: "00:00",
          leave: "",
          out: "00:00",
          weekend: "sun"
        },
        {
          attendance: "00:00",
          date: "2019-10-17",
          fv: "",
          holiday: "",
          in: "00:00",
          leave: "",
          out: "00:00",
          weekend: ""
        },
        {
          attendance: "00:00",
          date: "2019-10-18",
          fv: "",
          holiday: null,
          in: "00:00",
          leave: "",
          out: "00:00"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      userName: "Admin",
      report: [
        {
          attendance: "00:00",
          date: "2019-10-16",
          fv: "",
          holiday: "",
          in: "00:00",
          leave: "",
          out: "00:00",
          weekend: "sun"
        },
        {
          attendance: "00:00",
          date: "2019-10-17",
          fv: "",
          holiday: "",
          in: "00:00",
          leave: "",
          out: "00:00",
          weekend: ""
        },
        {
          attendance: "00:00",
          date: "2019-10-18",
          fv: "",
          holiday: null,
          in: "00:00",
          leave: "",
          out: "00:00"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

I need to achieve this type of output.( just for example)[image: desired output]

Here I need nested columns for example in image (1 to 16),whose title will be "date" and field will be "in". How can I achieve this type of complex JSON binding in kendo grid Angular

Comment: You might need to use spanned columns: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/spanned/

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ludwig.After seeing the example of spanned columns ,I didnt come into a conclusion.Actually thats not my requirement.First Two columns are made fixed.I implemented this by using *NgFor to the columns and made columns nested but thats not a good practise i guess!! so is there any other way to bind this type of JSON array to kendo grid?